# Typescript: transform required properties to optional

Tags: typescript

How can non-optional properties be transformed to optional ones?
Here's the code:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: any // no '?', hence this prop is required
}

type KeysOfFoo = {
  [K in keyof Foo]: any
}

const keysOfFoo: KeysOfFoo = {} // No tsc error wanted here, got: "type '{}' is not assignable to type KeysOfFoo"
```

Comment: Have a look at the `Partial` type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: Thanks, you gave me correct direction. I just added question mark immediately after 'key' part: `[K in keyof Foo]?: any`

Comment: In case it's not immediately clear from the linked document, `Partial` is part of TypeScript. Additionally, there is [a bunch of other really useful types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.0.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1351-L1409).

Comment: Thanks! I got it. In my case I cannot use `Partial` because my value is not `Foo[K]`, but completely different value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just one change here, although it does not apply to the problem in the question. The solution here retains the types for the keys as well..
Read more here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types

```js
interface Foo {
  bar: any // no '?', hence this prop is required
}

type KeysOfFoo = {
  [K in keyof Foo]?: Foo[K] // so that it retains the types
}
```